# Apple App Store ok with Trigger Reload?

Tags: trigger.io

Trigger "Reload" feature allows updating apps bypassing App Store approval process.

Does this violate App Store terms?

http://trigger.io/cross-platform-application-development-blog/2012/08/16/announcing-trigger-io-reload-iterate-fast-on-mobile/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

iOS apps built using Trigger.io Forge roughly consist of the UIWebView component provided by the iOS SDK, which loads your HTML/CSS/JavaScript, whether it's bundled with the app or fetched using Trigger.io Reload.

The iOS Developer Program License Agreement actually covers the topic of updating UIWebView assets without the use of the App Store distribution mechanism:

> 3.3.2 An Application may not download or install executable code.  Interpreted code may  only be used in an Application if all scripts,
>   code and interpreters are packaged in the Application  and not
>   downloaded. The only exception to the foregoing is scripts and code
>   downloaded and run  by Apple's built-in WebKit framework, provided
>   that such scripts and code do not change the  primary purpose of the
>   Application by providing features or functionality that are
>   inconsistent with  the intended and advertised purpose of the
>   Application as submitted to the App Store.

From https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/ios/standard/ios_program_standard_agreement_20120912.pdf (you need to be signed in to the Apple Developer Centre to see it though).

Comment: Hmmm, does Trigger.io Reload / PhoneGap Build Hydration fall into this exception category "being downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework"? I think not - which is a bummer.

Comment: Trigger.io's reload feature should fall into this exception, as it only updates the HTML/JS/CSS which is used in "Apple's built-in WebKit framework". We at Hojoki use Trigger.io Reload for our app and everything is fine with Apple.

Comment: As I understand the sentence "being downloaded and run by Apple's built-in WebKit framework" it requires code to both be downloaded by WebKit and run by WebKit. I'm sure Trigger.io/Phonegap meet the latter requirement. I'm not sure about the former. Does Reload download updates using WebKit framework or native code?

@PatrickRudolph thanks for chiming in. Knowing that someone already does it in production makes my feel much more confident.

Comment: I too wonder about the "downloaded by webkit" condition. Implementations I am familiar with use a cordova plugin to download and symlink the html/js/css bundle.