# iOS App Store approval rate for trigger.io apps

Tags: ios, cross-platform, appstore-approval, trigger.io, hybrid-mobile-app

We are ready to start the development of an using trigger.io, however some last minute external feedback pretends that trigger.io apps are systematically being rejected by Apple since the launch of their new Reload system (which pushes updated HTML/CSS/JS code without having to re-sublit to Apple for app updates).

The only reply regarding this topic on stackoverflow ([Apple App Store ok with Trigger Reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358329/apple-app-store-ok-with-trigger-reload)) was issued by one of the founders of Trigger.io, so I'm really looking for some totally independent feedback on this.

Can anyone provide any real-life feedback on this ? Has anyone ever succesfully submitted an app to the store ?

Trigger.io's page https://trigger.io/examples/ provides very few examples of submitted apps, so it isn't very convincing either...

Any feedback greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 4):

At Hojoki, we're successfully submitting [an app built on Trigger.io](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/hojoki/id525010205) to the App Store for over a year now. We're actively using Reload (e.g. pushed reloads to all our iOS users three times in April)  and never experienced any issues regarding approval and Reload.

There were two times that the app has been rejected (related to meta data stuff..), however this had nothing to do with Reload or Trigger.io at all.

Answer (score 3):

The only [Reload](https://trigger.io/reload/)-related app store rejection we know of happened on May 9th (six days ago). This was due to Reload files not being marked as exempt from iCloud and iTunes backups.

There are loads of apps using Reload live in the app store, so it's not a general problem - it's just that this particular app was using Reload to distribute >100MB files.

Nevertheless, [v1.4.46](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/release_notes.html) of the Trigger.io platform contains a fix which sets the no-backup flag, to be extra safe.